# Check if a String has vowels, and create a new String that doubles the consonants

Tags: java, loops

So here's what I'm trying to do. I take a given string, and make a new string. The new string will be the same as the original string, but will have the consonants doubled.

For example, `rabbit` becomes `rrabbitt` and so forth. It only doubles the consonants that aren't already doubled.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//  Returns a new string in which all consonants in the given string are doubled. 
//  Consonants that are already doubled are not doubled again. 
//  For example, doubleConsonants("rabbit") returns "rrabbitt". 
//  It is assumed that in the given string is alphabetic and that no character 
//  appears more than twice in a row.
//  Parameters:
//  s - given string
//  Returns new string with all consonants doubled
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static String doubleConsonants(String s) {

    String newString = "";
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        boolean hasVowel = false;
        for (int n = 0; n == 10; n++){

            if ( vowels.charAt(n) == s.charAt(i)) {

                newString += s.charAt(i);
                i++;
                hasVowel = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hasVowel = false && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1) && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i-1)) {

            newString += s.charAt(i);
            i++;                
        }
        else if (hasVowel = false) {

            newString += s.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Apparently there are some issues with "dead code" and the boolean hasVowels is "not used". What am I screwing up?

Comment: Your for loop never works. The one with for (int n = 0; n == 10; n++). the for loop works only when the condition n == 10 is true which is never.

Comment: I thought n = 0 was the start point and n == 10 was the end...

Comment: how would I change that so it would go through 10 iterations?

Comment: I posted a solution if you like it, mark it correct or else for your algorithm to make it work you need to change it to n <= 10 to make it work till n is greater than 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static String doubleConsonants(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?i)(([^aeiou])\\2+)|([^aeiou])", "$1$3$3");
}
```

Comment: @Muldawg2020 See documents [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: That;s insane. Thanks for showing me. It's still WAAAYY over my head, but I'm going to learn it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do one thing. Using a contains() method will greatly reduce all your work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { // traverse through the string
    if (i < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
          newString += s.charAt(i);   // handles the double constant special condition like bb in rabbit
          i++;
    } else if (vowels.contains("" + s.charAt(i))) {  //check if the letter is a vowel
         newString += s.charAt(i); // if yes, add it once
    } else {
         newString += "" + s.charAt(i) +s.charAt(i); // else add it twice
    }
}
```

At the end of this code block, you will have the required string stored in newString. you can read more about [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Tried it, but it gives an error on your 2nd line:

`The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)`

Can I fix that by making `vowels` an array?

Comment: Just convert it to a string by making it "" + s.charAt(i)

Comment: yea unfortunately doesn't work for some reason... I read through it and it seems to work in concept, but it isn't performing the way it should. Like if you try it out on `rabbit` it doesn't return `rrabbitt`....

Comment: Will work fine with the new update. I checked it on my machine. The problem is char + char is like ASCII values added together so you might be getting some wierd numbers but since you add "" +char it first converts to string and then it should work

Comment: ahhh i see what the issue is. I tried it out on `rabbit`. Expected: `rrabbitt`, actual return: `rrabbbbitt`. Looks like it was returning the consonants twice

Comment: So would my original line of code work to make it correct?

        `if (hasVowel = false && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1) && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i-1)) {

            newString += s.charAt(i);
            i++;                
        }
`

Comment: Didnt you want that? If not, then just add a new condition to check if s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1) then ignore the double addition path.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is that the if-statements towards the bottom are using the assignment operator. You want to use the double-equals to test the value. I'll have to look more closely at the logic for more.